# How do I allow for null values to show in MySQL Query while joining two tables?

Tags: mysql, sql

> Write a query to return the Customer ID, Customer Name and number of orders. Include all customers, even if they don't have any orders.

I have two tables. Table Customers:

```
Customer ID(employees)  Name (employees)
1                       Davolio
2                       John
```

And Table Orders:

```
OrderID (orders)    CustomerID (orders)
10248               1                  
10278               1
```

---

I'm trying to combine the two for the desired output:

```
CustomerID              Customer Name           Number of Orders
1                       Davolio                 2            
2                       John
```

However, I'm getting:

```
CustomerID              Customer Name           Number of Orders
1                       Davolio                 2
```

Because my MySQL query is not showing "null values":

```
SELECT CustomerID,CustomerName, COUNT(*) Number_of_Orders
FROM customers A 
INNER JOIN orders B using(CustomerID)
GROUP BY CustomerID
```

How would I solve this problem?

I've tried adding "OR Number_of_Order IS NULL" to the bottom but I'm getting this error:

Error: Unknown column 'Number_of_Order' in 'group statement' — ERROR CODE 1054

Thank you.

Comment: Use `LEFT JOIN` rather than `INNER JOIN`. Didn't your textbook explain this before giving this assignment?

Comment: @Barmar im selft teaching RN using online searches

Comment: Still, 5 minutes in the company of any basic, introductory book or tutorial will address these sorts of questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN`.

```sql
SELECT CustomerID,CustomerName, COUNT(*) Number_of_Orders
FROM customers A 
LEFT JOIN orders B using(CustomerID)
GROUP BY CustomerID
```